# Why is my PHP class acting static?

Tags: php

New to PHP.

I have created a simple class:

```
 class User
{
    private $name;
    private $password;
    private $email;

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function setName($value)
    {       
        $this->name = $value;
    }
    public function setPassword($value)
    {
        $this->password = $value;
    }
    public function setEmail($value)
    {
        $this->email = $value;
    }
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

I created 2 instances of this class and stored the first instance into an array. I am then checking to see if the second instance exists in the array (the one I did not add to the array). For some reason in_array() always returns '1' or true.

It turns out that the array now somehow contains the second user object that I did not explicitly add to the array. As if the properties of User are behaving like static class members. What am I missing?

```
$user = new User();
    $user::setName('Nick');
    $user::setEmail('bbbb@gmail.com');
    $user::setPassword('bbbbb');

    $somethingelse = new User();
    $somethingelse::setName('Mindy');
    $somethingelse::setEmail('a@gmail.com');
    $somethingelse::setPassword('aaaa');

    $arr = array('users'=>$user); //add first object to array

    echo in_array($somethingelse,$arr); //check if second object is in array

    echo $arr['users']::getName(); //Prints mindy
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're using the namespace resolution operator `::`, rather than the instance dereferencing operator `->`. The first invokes the method on the class, the second on an instance. If you turn on `E_STRICT` error reporting (which you should!), you'll see a bunch of warnings about calling instance methods statically.

To fix this, use `$user->setName('Nick');` (with similar changes elsewhere).

Comment: ahh.. the new operator is returning a pointer to my object. Makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
->
```

instead of

```
::
```

> In short, it’s used to access Static or Constant members of a class.

it would result in

```
$user = new User();
    $user->setName('Nick');
    $user->setEmail('bbbb@gmail.com');
    $user->setPassword('bbbbb');

    $somethingelse = new User();
    $somethingelse->setName('Mindy');
    $somethingelse->setEmail('a@gmail.com');
    $somethingelse->setPassword('aaaa');

    $arr = array('users'=>$user); //add first object to array

    echo in_array($somethingelse,$arr); //check if second object is in array

    echo $arr['users']->getName(); //Prints mindy
```